# Apache stopped working on LAN when on reboot

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver, lan

I set up an Apache server on an old laptop last night (apache2) just to play around on. It worked fine on my laptop, and I could get web pages from it from other computers on my local network. After rebooting the computer, however, the Apache server is not visible on the local network.

nmap TCP connect(), Syn, and ping scans showed that the host was down. An nmap -PN scan, however, showed that the host is up and all 1000 scanned ports are filtered.

PHP, MySQL, and PhpMyAdmin are all still working perfectly on localhost, the only problem I can find is that nothing works on local network.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You havent said on your OS, but, there could be a local firewall, or, a change of IP (it could be DHCP) or DNS hasnt caught up properly with DHCP..

a `netstat -a` should tell you what ports are being listened on. Check its not just listening on 127.0.0.1

Comment: OS is Ubuntu (Desktop) 10.04.
My router is using DHCP, but ifconfig showed that the IP stayed the same when it started up. I got web pages through the browser on the server itself from 192.168.?.? but when I entered that same IP on another computer on the network, no results.

Comment: Can the other machines ping that address?

Comment: With an nmap ping scan (-sP) they could not, with nmap -PN, they could.

Comment: Hmm,if ping is blocked and http is blocked it screams out its being blocked on the webbox, as subnet wise thats the only place you could realistically do it.

Comment: What could cause that? Any ideas as to how I can get it working?

Comment: ipchains would be the likely culpret, but it does seem odd it would kick in without knowledge. If you just "ping 192.168...." not use the nmap tool, does that work?